# Passing ivar through NSNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, nsnotifications

I'm study about NSNotificationCenter. Here is my code

Observer.m

```
//note init method is not complete here

    -(id) init
    {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
             addObserver:self 
             selector:@selector(reciveTestNotification:) 
             name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];

    }

    -(void)reciveTestNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        if([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Succesfuly received the test notification");
        }
    }
```

Osender.m

```
-(void)reciveTestNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Succesfuly received the test notification");
    }
}
```

I think that I undestand how NSNotification works, but how to pass ivar via NSNotification ?

Lets say Osender.h have this code

Osender.h

```
@interface Osender : NSObject
{
  IBOutlet UITextField *txt;
}

@property (nonatopic, copy) IBOutlet (UITextField *) *txt
```

How to notify reciveTestNotification and pass data to it when user type or change something on txt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSNotification` class has a property for additional data that you might want to send with your notification, `userInfo`.

You post it like this:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:txt forKey:@"textField"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo]
```

And get it like this:

```
- (void)reciveTestNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UITextField *textField = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"textField"];
}
```

Now `textField` has the reference to your `UITextField`.

Comment: I get Semantic Issue: Method '-hasObjectForKey:' not found. I guess this is because notification not respond to that method ?

Comment: Fixed. My mistake. You don't have to check if an object exists in `NSDictionary`. It just returns `nil` if there's no object.

Answer (score 1):

You can put custom data into the notification's `userInfo`, which is a `NSDictionary` instance. You need to ensure that the keys created in the dictionary by the notification's poster are the same as the keys expected by the consumers of the notification.

Answer (score 0):

use this method of NSNotificationCenter

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

and set userInfo to an NSDictionary with the data you want to pass:

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object", @"key", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:nil userInfo:infoDict];
```